# Chrome does not stream content from Django's StreamingHttpResponse

Tags: django, gunicorn

A year ago, I used Django's StreamingHttpResponse to stream a text file and Chrome immediately displayed every chunk of text that it received. Now, with the same code, Chrome only displays the text when it completely loads the text file, thus risks server timeout. This does not happen with Firefox.

I created a simple test:

```
# views.py
import time
from django.views import generic

class TestEditView(generic.TemplateView):
    def generator(self):
        for _ in range(15):
            time.sleep(1)
            yield 'THIS IS {}\n'.format(_)
            print('LOG: THIS IS {}\n'.format(_))

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return StreamingHttpResponse(self.generator(),
          content_type="text/plain; charset=utf-8")
```

If I access that view in Firefox, that browser will print out 'THIS IS ....' each second for 15 seconds. But in Chrome, the browser will wait 15 seconds, then print out all of the 'THIS IS...', even though the development server log 'LOG: THIS IS...' once a second.

I wonder if there is any subtlety in this problem that I missed. Thank you.

Python: 3.6.2.
Django: 1.10.5

Comment: I think you need to set the transfer encoding to ``chunked`` else the browser may or may not be waiting for the complete file.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the question here. It sounds like you have a possible bug report for the chrome developers?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the content_type from "text/plain" to "text/html" or removing the content_type altogether solves the problem - it makes Chrome render each chunk of text immediately after it receives.