# How to render a page with multiple parts progressively using django?

Tags: django, stream

I am developing a website using `django`. The website has a page which takes more than 1 seconds to be rendered. I want to load this page progressively like Google. Google first loads the input then after some moments loads search results. like this:

[image]

I use `StreamingHttpResponse` (described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse)) to load page progressively. My `views.py` is here:

```
import time
from django.http.response import StreamingHttpResponse

class TestStreamingLoading(View):
    def get(self, request):
        response = StreamingHttpResponse(streaming_content=self.generate_stream_response())
        return response

    def generate_stream_response(self):
        yield 'data1 '
        time.sleep(4)
        yield 'data2'
```

My problem is the browser does not render anything till total page is downloaded. The browser shows nothing before 4 seconds and after that shows `data1 data2`. But I want to show `data1` at the beginning and show `data1 data2` after 4 seconds. How can I do this?

Comment: Use js on the front end.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers you mean `ajax`? It is slow.

Comment: ajax is neither "slow" nor "fast" by itself, it's just a plain simple http request / response cycle. It will be "slow" if your server takes ages to return a response and / or if your js code (updating the page from the response) takes ages to do it's job. And anyway, this is basically how you implement progressive loading of a page - unless you want to go [the full PWA route](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Introduction) of course.

Comment: I do not want to send multiple `http` request to my server (one for loading part1 and another one for loading part2). It is slower than waiting for part2. I have tested `ajax` before.

Comment: Once again, whether it's "slower" or not depends on your server, your js code etc - the fact you "have tested ajax before" doesn't mean much here (I can easily write a pure C app that's slower than a python one). But well, let's wait and see if anyone comes with a better solution...

Comment: Oh and yes: if you haven't done so already (you didn't mention it) you may also want to try and fix the root issue (why is your page taking so much time to render) before thinking of progressive rendering. Also note that django has a rather effective cache system that can save a lot of time if well used.

Comment: Here is some similar questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46705905/chrome-does-not-stream-content-from-djangos-streaminghttpresponse

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15116881/django-streaminghttpresponse-into-a-template

But none of them did not work.

Comment: Your code seems okay. Maybe send data using appropriate content type. `text/plain` in your case.

Comment: @xyres This is `text/html` but does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason can be `gzip` middleware. `gzip` encoding makes the content to some chunks, so it waits to complete a chunk then will compress and send the chunk. If you want to load a streaming page, you should use [`brotli`](https://pypi.org/project/django-brotli/) encoding middleware for django. `brotli` has been made for loading streaming page by Google. more information is [here](https://github.com/google/brotli).